# Java: pass from CSV into HashMap and Print Key and values

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I have a CSV file with 5 rows, and three pieces of data separated by comas on each row.
Row Example: Drew, 37, 150.5
I am trying to read the data from the CSV, into a HashMap and then print out the HashMap Keys and Values. Right now I'm only getting empty brackets to print out. Code below, I'm taking an online course and having trouble reaching the professor, and have tried several online resources, appreciate anyone's advice so I can learn. TY!

````
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Person> myPeople = new HashMap();
    try {
      File myObj = new File("people.csv");
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = myReader.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println(myPeople);
      }
      myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}```
My current output is below, without keys or values.
 java -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* Main
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}

````

Comment: You are creating the empty myPeople HashMap, you don't add anything to it, and you print the empty HashMap in every loop iteration, so it's empty every time.

Comment: Thank you @Isaac , I was trying to add the file "people.csv" by passing through the scanner class. Havnt been able to read scanner class back to the HashMap

Comment: Something simple you could do is: `String[] fields = data.split(",");` This will split the line using the comma as separator (use comma or whatever the separator is in your CSV). It will give you an array of strings. And then you can use the array to create a `Person` object, for example, using a constructor with parameters: `Person person = new Person(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]);` And finally put the person in your HashMap: `myPeople.put(person.name, person);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added anything to your map, that's why it is just printing empty map ({}) on each iteration. Here is an example of how to do this:

```java
public class Main {

    static class Person {
        String name;
        int age;
        int height;

        public Person(String name, int age, int height) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Person person = (Person) o;
            return age == person.age && height == person.height && name.equals(person.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, age, height);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", age=" + age +
                    ", height=" + height +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static final String csv =
            "Drew, 37, 168\n" +
                    "Bob, 30, 170";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(csv)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
                map.put(lineParts[0], new Person(lineParts[0], Integer.parseInt(lineParts[1]), Integer.parseInt(lineParts[2])));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Output:
{Bob=Person{name='Bob', age=30, height=170}, Jack=Person{name='Jack', age=37, height=168}}

Answer (score 0):

You should be printing data rather than myPeople, as you have not added anything to myPeople yet.

You can use myPeople.put(key, value) to add elements to your map, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-put-method-in-java/.

Then you can use myPeople.get(key) to retrieve the value, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/.